# « Organiser des flashmobs » : est-ce bien « organiser » dont il s'agit ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, verbes, formulation-idiomatique, anglicismes, mots-composés

> À Moscou et Saint-Pétersbourg des habitants ont **organisé des flashmobs**
> de la Saint-Valentin dans des cours d’immeubles et sur les places,
> allumant leurs lampes sur leurs téléphones pour soutenir l’opposant
> emprisonné. ([LaPresse](https://www.lapresse.ca/international/europe/2021-02-14/l-amour-plus-fort-que-la-peur/des-femmes-russes-manifestent-leur-soutien-a-l-epouse-de-navalny.php) via AFP)

Il s'agit d'une [*mobilisation*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26539726)/[*foule/rassemblement éclair*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8359777). S'agit-il d'une chose qui s'[*organise*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/organise), est-ce une tautologie ; la formulation (avec un verbe relié au mot) avec le terme de langue anglaise (*flashmobs*) diffère-t-elle de celle en français ; aurait-on formulé différemment, comment et pourquoi ?

Answer (score 3):

Un(e) flashmob est par nature organisé(e).

Il ne s'agit pas d'une manifestation spontanée mais bien de l'action coordonnée et synchronisée (à 20 h pour celle-là) d'un ensemble de participant mis dans la confidence par un ou plusieurs **organisateurs**, ici l'équipe d'Alexeï Navalny puis les habitants de Moscou et Saint-Pétersbourg.

Comment: Oui, ce qui est _éclair_ c'est la durée typique du rassemblement et la dispersion qui s'ensuit, et non son organisation. Est-ce que ça change quelque chose la voix active/passive du verbe _organiser_ ici ? Ou trouves-tu que de dire _organiser_, puis _allumant_ illustre une confusion du procès de l'action ?

Comment: Oui, il y a une confusion, ou au moins un raccourci entre les deux étapes.

Comment: Ah tiens je réalise avec ta réponse qu'apparemment il n'y a pas encore un consensus sur le fait que flashmob est masculin ou féminin.

Comment: @LaurentS. Oui, flashmob et covid-19 sont du même genre... ;-)

Comment: Ah, le fameux générique sous-jacent...

Answer (score 0):

Cette idée d'organisation dans la réalisation d'un évènement, laquelle n'est effectuée, de par la nature de cette réalisation, que par la force agissante d'une quasi-spontanéité, ne peut que paraitre incongrue. Elle l'est, à mon avis. Une appréhension plus juste du phénomène semble nécessaire. Il existe bien une fondation organisatrice mais c'est un état de chose politico-culturel qui est à la base non pas d'*une* occurrence de manifestation éclair de cette sorte mais de *toutes* : elle implique un ou plusieurs précédents,  parmi les individus susceptibles de se joindre à un rassemblement éclair elle implique un échange d'idées sur la valeur du procédé, plus ou moins elle implique le développement d'un certain esprit de militantisme, en bref une éducation, et en cela on peut  parler d'un d'organisation ; on pourra trouver probablement d'autres aspects de la fondation de ce  phénomène essentiellement politique. Si c'est cette base qui permet l'effet éclair, elle n'agit cependant plus dans la réalisation d'un des évènements auxquels elle peut donner naissance ;  chacun de ces évènements, néanmoins, ne peut se matérialiser que par un acte initial qui lui est propre, un acte de mise en branle ou comme je préfèrerais le dire, de déclenchement, et donc je parlerais du *déclenchement* d'un rassemblement éclair.

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse C'est bien une erreur (de l'anglais « through the agency »).